# Elasticsearch failed to connect to master although the http request is available

Tags: elasticsearch

I use three servers to testify the Elasticsearch's Cluster function.
This is one of my servers' key configs:

- Server1:(public address: 115.159.157.163)

  ```
  cluster.name: czqofnju
  node.name: qiang_server
  network.host: 0.0.0.0
  discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["115.159.156.116", "182.254.212.194"]
  ```

The server's public ip address is 115.159.157.163. But when start elasticsearch, its log shows that it bounds to an private address

```
[2017-02-18T10:36:14,491][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] 
[qiang_server] publish_address {10.105.197.255:9300}, bound_addresses {10.105.197.255:9300}
```

Then when I try to use another server to connect to this server, it shows:

```
[2017-02-18T11:31:05,664][WARN ][o.e.d.z.ZenDiscovery     ]
[dbc_server] failed to connect to master 
[{qiang_server}{GYT635GNSaqOpBdQK4ZcGg}{O1sDFagITmWFnXRBf-uweA}{10.105.197.255}{10.105.197.255:9300}], retrying... 
org.elasticsearch.transport.ConnectTransportException: [qiang_server][10.105.197.255:9300] connect_timeout[30s]
```

This server's key config are following:

- Server2:(public address: 182.254.212.194)

  ```
  cluster.name: czqofnju
  node.name: dbc_server
  network.host: 0.0.0.0
  discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["115.159.157.163"]
  ```

And if I try to send a HTTP request to Server1, it can respond.

Now my question is: why the server2 can reach server1 and get it's private address:10.105.197.255 and its node name: qiang_server, but still not able to connect to the server1?

I understand that 10.105.197.255 is a private address but server2 has found server1, why they still cannot join together?

The following are some of my attempts, which all failed:
Clearly 10.105.197.255 is a private address,
I have tried some other configs for network.host like

1. *site*:still the same address
2. 115.159.157.163: this is my server's public address, while exception implying that can not bind to the request address
3. *global*: turning out with exception "No up-and-running global-scope (public) addresses found"

   ```
     System: CentOS 7.2 4
     JVM: OpenJDK 1.8.0_121
     Elasticsearch: 5.2.1
   ```

   Any suggestions will help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please verify  that you are using NAT for that public IP address. If so, your setup isn't supported.

To verify:

```
ip a
```

If you dont see your public IP address on an interface listed, then you are using NAT. and thats why your `network.host: 115.159.157.163` is failing to bind.

[Source](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/problem-setting-up-cluster-with-nat-address/18152/7)

If your using a cloud provider like `AWS`, you should setup `VPC` or whatever depending on the cloud provider and make `elasticsearch` bind to private ip addresses reachable by other nodes to form the cluster. Then you bind an elastic ip(Public IP) to your hosts for external HTTP access.

Comment: Thanks, that hits the problem. I will try to bind to a private address.